# (Java) When trying to return a new subvector of custom Vector class, my method replaces the last element with zero. Why?

Tags: java, arrays, object, copy

I am just learning how to work with classes and objects, and am writing different methods to work with the Vector class I created.

I have written two working methods to add and insert elements, and am now trying to use either of those in a new method, the aim of which is to create a new Vector subvector object, that only contains elements from index a to index b-1, but has the same capacity as the original.

I have tried using both insert and add methods, the insert method seems to break the loop too soon and only returns the first element, and the add method almost returns the correct result, but replaces the last element with zero.

My first approach was to copy and insert elements like you do with arrays, but that returns the same result. Why is my code returning such a result?

(English is not my first language, so most of the names are in Slovene, the most important ones are translated for clarity)

This is what the class looks like:

```
    public class VektorInt{
    private int[] elementi;
    private int stElementov;

private static final int START_CAPACITY = 10;
//konstanta, lahko jo večkrat uporabimo

public VektorInt(int startCapacity){
    this.elementi = new int[startCapacity];
    this.stElementov = 0;
}
public VektorInt() {
    this(START_CAPACITY);
}
```

and these are the methods used to manipulate the objects:

```
public void set(int index, int value){
    if(index > this.elementi.length){
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException
    }
    this.elementi[index] = value;
}
public void add(int value){
    this.expandIfNeeded();
    this.elementi[this.stElementov] = value;
    this.stElementov++;
}
private void expandIfNeeded(){
    if (this.stElementov >= this.elementi.length){
        int[] stariElementi = this.elementi;
        this.elementi = new int[2*stariElementi.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < this.stElementov; i++){
            this.elementi[i] = stariElementi[i];
        }
        
    }  
}
public void insert(int index, int value){
    this.expandIfNeeded();
    for(int i = this.stElementov - 1; i >= index; i--){
        this.elementi[i + 1] = this.elementi[i];
    }
    this.elementi[index] = value;
    this.stElementov++;
}
```

and this is the method in question:

```
public VektorInt subvector(int start, int end){
    VektorInt subvector = new VektorInt(this.elementi.length);
    for(int i = start; i <= (end) - 1; i++){
        subvector.add(elementi[i])
    }
    subvector.stElementov++;
    return subvector;
}
```

which for System.out.println(vektor.subvector(0, 6)) returns [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 0].

What is the reason for the subvector method stopping after the first element, if I exchange subvector.add(elementi[i]) for subvector.insert(elementi[i])? If I initialize a vector with a big enough start capacity, shouldn't this work as well?

Comment: It's not "replacing" the last element with zero. Zero is simply the default int value and you only fill from indexes 0 to 5 (end - 1) in your subvector method if you call it with the arguments 0 and 6. So element at index 6 will still have the default value.

Comment: The error might either be that you initialize your Subvector with the same size as the original, despite it being smaller instead of initializing it with the needed size that you can calculate by doing end - start - 1.  Or that you didn't intend to have the end parameter be exclusive and stop your loop that copies elements 1 iteration to early. At least those would be my guesses from a quick look at your code.

Comment: I forgot to add -1 in the explanation, the prompt for this assignment says that the method has to return a vector that contains only elements from a to b-1 but has the same capacity as the original, edited my post a bit to clarify. Since the subvector is supposed to be the size of the original, why doesn't it then also print the other zeros, up to this.elementi.length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the elements to `subvector` with `subvector.add(elementi[i]);` correctly changes the subvectors `stElementov`.

After that you write `subvector.stElementov++;` which increases the size of the `subvector` without actually adding an element.

That means that the actual size of `subvector` is now one bigger than the number of elements added.

For this extra element the value is whatever the default value in an `int[]` is - which happens to be zero (0). This is the extra zero that you see when you print out the `subvector`.